# Leak from the connection between downspout adapter and drain pipe

Tags: leak, downspout, adapter

I have a downspout adapter (2x3x3 [NDS 903](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-2-in-x-3-in-x-3-in-Styrene-H-x-H-Offset-Down-Spout-Adapter-903/100192766)) connecting a downspout to a drain pipe. The adapter is female, drain pipe is male, there is leak from the connection because it is not very tight:[image]

How can I stop the leak? I have some ideas:

1. Change the adapter to male or add another adapter so it can fit inside the drain pipe. But I couldn't find such adapter anywhere.
2. Use cement to connect the adapter and the drain pipe. The adapter is pvc. I am not sure if the drain pipe is also pvc. Please see the picture: [image] What type of cement should I use?
3. Wrap tape around the drain pipe to make the connection tight.
4. Use silicone sealant to seal the leak.

Which approach is the best? Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: The problem with glue or silicone is that those adapters can get broken.  It then becomes a pain to remove.  Would try tape/rubber first, and then maybe silicone if not happy.  Have you looked for AL/metal adapter that could be made to fit inside by squeezing.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks. I haven't looked for metal adapter. I just found [one](https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/Square-to-round-downspout-adapter-p218871198), very expensive. I will try tape first.

Comment: _How much_ is it leaking, and how can you tell? The outside of the downspout and the outside of this pipe _are_ going to get wet when it's raining, as will the ground below them. Unless the _vast majority_ of the water is leaking out here, I just don't see how this can possibly be a problem. Additionally, usually only the actual gutters are sealed, all downspout joints as just a press fit with a screw or pop-rivet to keep them from coming apart, they're not sealed to make them water tight.